# move_uploaded_file() not working for video upload

Tags: php

I know there are a lot of posts regarding this problem, however I feel I have taken all steps which were referred in previous answers and I have still had no luck.

I am trying to upload a video file which is `10MB` and I have made changes in both my `php.ini` and `.htaccess` files, neither of which have rectified my problem:

**.htaccess**

```
# Restrict the maximum upload size to 32MB
php_value upload_max_filesize 32000000000
php_value post_max_size 32000000000

# Compensate for slow connection times, otherwise video uploads may not complete
php_value max_execution_time 99999999
php_value max_input_time 99999999
```

I know for a fact that the FILE data is getting passed correctly as a) the file contents reflects what I've uploaded and b) My upload conditions are satisfied right up to the block where `move_uploaded_file()` is called.

**$_FILE contents**

```
array(1) {
["video_file"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
        string(11) "pump2_c.mp4"
      ["type"]=>
        string(9) "video/mp4"
      ["tmp_name"]=>
        string(14) "/tmp/php301tts"
      ["error"]=>
        int(0)
      ["size"]=>
        int(8368613)
    }
}
```

When I call for my video file to be moved I run

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'], './public/video/' . $_FILES['video_file']['name']);
```

However, whenever I `var_dump()` the result of the method it always returns `false`, does anybody have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I didn't mean to put them in my post, was formatting :)

Comment: why is there . in path???  './public/video/'

Comment: I tried using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but that did not work neither. `public` folder is at the root of my app so `./` gets me to root does it not?

Comment: Not sure about that but have you checked the chmod for you upload folder? It **MUST** be 777 in order for move_uploaded_files to work. I don't know if it returns a false value for that issue though.

Comment: @Rems and that is where I facepalm!  I only just created this folder, so no I won't have `rwx` permissions over it - completely forgot I took that step when I made my `img` folder, thankyou!

Comment: @AlexSims It happened to me 2 weeks ago, don't worry ;)

Comment: @Rems did you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it? - thanks again :)

Comment: @AlexSims Just did it, cheers! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59647/discussion-between-alex-sims-and-rems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `move_uploaded_files()` to run correctly on your script, the destination folder for the uploaded files has to be `chmod 777`, which means 'Everybody can read, write and execute in this folder'; because PHP is logged as 'Public' and thus cannot write in a folder with no public write access.

You can perform such actios by typing `chmod -R 777 /your/upload/folder` on Unix console or using the Folder Properties Menu on Windows.